# Php File Output Variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay I'm working with this code

```
$Output = $FirstName '_' $LastName '_' $AccountNumber;
file_put_contents($Output, 'ENTER HTML');
```

How can I make it output the file by the variable determined ? For some reason it just returns an error.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate those strings and store it in `$Output`?

Comment: Ya I thought that might help for some reason but ya I was trying to concatenate them then use that as the output so basically what I really want is

     file_put_contents($FirstName '_' $LastName '_' $AccountNumber '.html', 'ENTER HTML');

Comment: i think you missed concatenate operator dot (.). $Output = $FirstName. '_' .$LastName. '_' .$AccountNumber;

Comment: I think you are new in PHP... are you...?? please post the value of `$Firstname`, `$Lastname` & `$accountNumber`... because I think the problem is in `$Output`... I use `file_put_contents` method a lot... I hope I can solve your problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to concatenate your 3 variables:

```
$Output = $FirstName . '_' . $LastName . '_' . $AccountNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Output = $FirstName .'_'. $LastName .'_'. $AccountNumber; // missing concatenate operator
file_put_contents($Output, 'ENTER HTML');
```

For help on file_put_contents visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php